# Rebuild database enable extension pg_stat_statements line got removed in schema file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

After rebuild the database by running:

```
bin/rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

`pg_stat_statements line` got removed in `db/schema.rb`.

Why this line got removed?

Answer (score 16):

The question is really how did it get there in the first place.  Did you restore the database from another source, perhaps?  This is fairly common if you're using a cloud provider (like Heroku, for example).

You can create an actual migration to add this extension:

```
class AddStatsExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension 'pg_stat_statements'
  end
end
```